# How to move String block of text xTab spaces to the right in Java?

Tags: java, text-alignment

If I have got a whole block of text as a `String`, which contains several new-lines.

For example: `System.out.println(myString)` would give:

```
<http-request>
  <param1>value</param>
  <param2>value</param>
</http-request>
```

And what I want to do is space the whole block three tab spaces to the right...

What is the best way to get this done?

Comment: Please refrain from adding noise like *"Thnx!"* to questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tried in code but sounds like the replace(regex, string) should work. 
Just go for replace("\n", "\n\t\t\t") -> one \t per tab space.

(replace from String's standardlib)

Comment: You would also need to add "\t\t\t" at the start of the first line.

Comment: Yes, that’s right. But I guess together this works well! - Should also be .replaceAll()

Answer (score 0):

Since java 12 you can use String.indent() method. For example

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("""
            <http-request>
              <param1>value</param>
              <param2>value</param>
            </http-request>
            """.indent(8));
}
```

will produce output like below

```
        <http-request>
          <param1>value</param>
          <param2>value</param>
        </http-request>
```